# Convert array from one format to another

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

In PHP I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Printed Chiffon Dress
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Printed Dress
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Printed Dress
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Printed Summer Dress
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Printed Summer Dress
        )

)
```

I want to convert that array into like this format

```
Array
(
    [0] => Printed Chiffon Dress
    [1] => Printed Dress
    [2] => Printed Dress
    [3] => Printed Summer Dress
    [4] => Printed Summer Dress
)
```

So can someone tell me how to convert the array as the above format? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP 5.5 and above, you can use `array_column`:

```
$new_array = array_column($array, 'name');
```

If you do not want any function at all, foreach will do just fine, then just push it in another container:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $value) {
    $new_array[] = $value['name'];
}
```